# Make checkout billing company field readonly keeping it active in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, readonly

Need to make an input read only in the checkout of WooCommerce 3.0 but still have the original content pass to the order. In this case the order needs to be passed to FishBowl.

I have tried many approaches here. This is the most recent...

```
add_action('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'disable_company_input', 10, 3);


function disable_company_input($args, $key, $value)
{
    if ($key == 'billing_company') {
        $args['custom_attributes'] = [
            'disabled' => 'disabled',
        ];
    }
    return $args;
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'billing_company_hidden_field');

function billing_company_hidden_field($checkout)
{

    echo '<input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="billing_company">';

}
```

I am trying to disable the users ability to change the billing_company, which this code did accomplish, but still have it pass to the final order, which I cannot seem to get it to do.

Thank you so much if you are able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead *(as a text field need to be `readonly`, but not `disabled`)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields' );
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If some data exists, it will appear on this field, but customer will not be able to add or change imput as it will be "readonly".

---

**Addition** - Check if Billing company has no value and hide/remove the field:

```
add_filter( 'check_billing_company_checkout_field' , 'check_billing_company_checkout_field' );
function billing_company_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    $billing_company = WC()->customer->get_billing_company();

    if( empty( $billing_company ) ) { // Remove field
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']); 
    } else { // Make readonly
        $fields['billing']['billing_company']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly'; 
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec this worked for what the client wanted. I appreciate you taking the time to respond to this. I still have much to learn ;)

Do you know what it would take to make the billing_company available only if no content existed in that field prior to the checkout page? But still locking it if there is content? I personally feel that would be a better UX then what the client originally wanted.